# RxJS 6 - Cancel / End a Pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, tap

Working with the new version of RxJS 6 and the pipe operator in particular. Currently using the pipe  to take the results of an API call and pass them to a series of additional tasks.

All works great, but can't seem to find a way to cancel or end a pipe should I encounter an issue. For example, I'm using the tap operator to check if the value is null. I then throw an error, but the pipe still appears to move to the next task, in this case concatmap.

Therefore, how do you end or cancel a pipe prematurely? Thanks in advance.

```typescript
getData(id: String): Observable<any[]> {
return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/path/${id}`).pipe(
   tap(evt => {
    if (evt == null) {
      return throwError(new Error("No data found..."));
    }
  }),
concatMap(
  evt =>
     <Observable<any[]>>(
        this.http.get<any[]>(
    `${this.baseUrl}/path/relatedby/${evt.child_id}`
      ).map(res =>( {"response1":evt, "response2":res}) )
 )
),
retry(3),
catchError(this.handleError("getData", []))
);}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can also cancel/end a pipe by using a signal `Subject` and the rxjs operator: `takeUntil`

**Example**

```js
httpGetSafe(path: string): Observable<Data> {
  const stopSignal$ = new Subject();

  return this.http.get<Data>(path).pipe(
    map(data => {
      const isBad = data === null;
      if (isBad) {
        stopSignal$.next();
      }
      return data;
    }),
    takeUntil(stopSignal$)
  );
}
```

Sometimes it's a bit simpler and more flexible than throwing errors...

Answer (score 12):

I tried the basic concept from what you have with this stackblitz and it worked. It cancelled the remaining operations. See the link below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ctwsd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Differences I see between your code and mine is that I used `throw` and not `throwError` (is that something you wrote?) and I'm just throwing the error ... not returning a thrown error.

Here is the code for reference:

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, tap, retry} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';

  constructor() {
    of('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
      .pipe(
       map(x => {
        if (x === 'c') {
          throw 'An error has occurred';
        }
        return x;
       }),
       tap(x => console.log('In tap: ', x)),
       retry(3),
       catchError(() => of('caught error!'))
      )
      .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

RXJS can throw and error to stop execution. The operator you applied in the pipe was just the wrong choice.

The 'tap' operator that you are using is only meant to be used to apply side-effect, i.e. make changes to the DOM, console.log, or change the values for some variables that you've got on your component (i.e. this.counter = someValue). The tap operator was not meant to to change the RXJS 'stream' - it will just return the same observable as it received. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap

On the other hand, operators that do work on the stream, like 'map', can throw errors. See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejinqh)

In summary, the code is

```
getData(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.httpGet('basePath').pipe(
      map(evt => {
        if (evt === null) {
          return throwError(new Error("No data found..."));
        } else {
          return evt;
        }
      }),
      concatMap(evt => {
        return this.httpGet(`childPath/${evt.serverResult}`); 
      }),
      map(res => {
        return {
          "response2": res.serverResult
        };
      }),
      retry(3),
      catchError(error => {
        console.log('error handled!');
        return of(null);
      })
    )
  }

  private httpGet(someString: string): Observable<{ serverResult: number }> {
    return timer(1000).pipe( // fake a server call that takes 1 second
      map(_ => { // fake a server result
      // Comment out the valid return and uncomment the null return to see it in action
        //return null;
        return { 
          serverResult: 1 
        }
      }) 
    );
  }
```

If you don't want to transform the error into a valid value in the stream, handle it in the error callback on the subscribe function.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to end the execution of the pipe without throwing an error you can return EMPTY.

```
myObservable.pipe(
  switchMap(c => c === null ? EMPTY: of(c)),
  tap(() => console.log('If c is null this is not executed anymore'))
);
```

Also the takeWhile operator is an option.

```
myObservable.pipe(
  takeWhile(c => c !== null),
  tap(() => console.log('If c is null this is not executed anymore'))
);
```

Both methods straight go to complete without go down the pipe!

Comment: The `switchMap` suggestion in part 1 worked great. Thank you.The `takeWhile` cancelled the entire pipe forever.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to suggest a different approach. This is in case you don't want to throw an error, just handle the case. **Create two observables and return one of them in a `switchMap` based on an `if` check.**

```
getData(id: String): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/path/${id}`).pipe(
   switchMap(evt => {
    if (evt == null) {
      // The chain will end here
      // subscription succeeds
      return of(null);
    }
    // This is an alternative chain 
    // You can construct further logic with rxjs operators
    return <Observable<any[]>>(
        this.http.get<any[]>(
    `${this.baseUrl}/path/relatedby/${evt.child_id}`
      ).map(res =>( {"response1":evt, "response2":res}) );
  }),

);}
```

Pardon any typos, this is just a quick example to demonstrate the approach.

Answer (score 2):

Observable functions are always wrapped internally in a try/catch block. Any error thrown in the stream will end the stream and call any error callbacks to subscribers or operators.

The problem here is with `throwError()`. I don't know what that function is and I don't recognize it as an Observable operator, but it looks like it's being used as one (and never subscribed to).

`tap` is usually only used for side effects only, as it is completely unable to affect the values in the stream. However, as I mentioned with the try/catch blocks before, you should just be able to `throw` a new `Error` and the stream will take care of the rest.

```typescript
getData(id: String): Observable<any[]> {
return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/path/${id}`).pipe(
   tap(evt => {
    if (evt == null) {
      throw new Error("No data found...");
    }
  }),
concatMap(
  evt =>
     <Observable<any[]>>(
        this.http.get<any[]>(
    `${this.baseUrl}/path/relatedby/${evt.child_id}`
      ).map(res =>( {"response1":evt, "response2":res}) )
 )
),
retry(3),
catchError(this.handleError("getData", []))
);}
```